# SKLabelNode multiple lines

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm having a bit of trouble with displaying a label with multiple lines in an `SKLabelNode`. First off, I know that there is no `lines` property or anything of the sort. I get there are GitHub projects out there that may be able to do it, but I would rather simply not use them.

The reason why I need multiple lines is due to the way my In-App Purchases work. Sometimes, descriptions can't all fit in one line. For example, rendered at the biggest DynamicType caption font size, the string:

```
Cheat and get 25% of the points needed for the "Chaos" theme!
```

would not fit on any of the iOS mobile phones on a portrait layout. I've tried calling this function:

```
-(NSString*)autoInsertLineBreaksInString:(NSString*)string {
    NSLog(@"Function called with %@", string);
    NSMutableArray* arrayOfSpaceIndexes = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableString* returnString = [string mutableCopy];
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        if ([string characterAtIndex:i] == [@" " characterAtIndex:0]) {
            NSLog(@"Adding %i to array of space indexes.", i);
            [arrayOfSpaceIndexes addObject:@(i)];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Not adding %i to array of space indexes.", i);
        }
    }
    [returnString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([[arrayOfSpaceIndexes objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)(floorf((arrayOfSpaceIndexes.count - 1) / 2))] unsignedIntegerValue], 1) withString:@"\n"];
    NSLog(@"Retruning %@", returnString);
    return returnString;
}
```

This inserts `\n` at the right spot and outputs this...

```
Cheat and get 25% of the
points needed for the "Chaos" theme.
```

...but the label node interprets `\n` as a space, giving me the original string. I really don't want to use a second label node. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: I don't think the SKLabelNode supports new-lines. Your going to have to build your own custom class for handling multiple lines using multiple nodes, or use a solution that already exists.

Comment: @DDPWNAGE No multi-lines with SKLabelNode and like EpicByte stated, you can use custom solutions, or make your own class. No other options. Just be aware if you decide to use multiple SKLabelNodes, that one SKLabelNode == 1 draw call. Multiple SKLabelNodes can't be drawn in single draw call like SKSpriteNode.

Comment: @DDPWNNAGE, I saw your note that you don't prefer this route, but If you do go with two label nodes, you might create a wrapper SKNode, and add the two SKLabelNodes to the wrapper. When you add the wrapper to your scene, you can hide/show/move/etc both nodes just by managing the wrapper.

Comment: @Thunk the reason why I didn't want to make to `SKLabelNode`s was because I didn't want to have to manage both of them (also, if I needed more lines, then I'd have to support them). Your comment will help me a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formalizing a comment into an answer: If you choose to go with multiple instances of `SKLabelNode`, you might create a wrapper `SKNode` and add all each `SKLabelNode` to the wrapper. When you add the wrapper to your scene, you can hide/show/move/etc all label nodes together just by managing the one wrapper.

Comment: I tried doing that. I ended up using a blank `SKEffectNode` because I can't add a `nil` node to the scene.

Answer (score 2):

This thread helped put me in the right direction. Here's my objective-c implementation of the suggested solution:

```
NSInteger fontSize = 40;
SKNode *messageNode;
messageNode = [[SKNode alloc] init];

NSArray *components = [messageString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

for(int i = 0; i < [components count]; i++){
    SKLabelNode *subNode = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Helvetica-Bold"];
    subNode.text = [components objectAtIndex:i];
    subNode.position = CGPointMake(0, -fontSize*i);
    subNode.fontSize = fontSize;
    subNode.fontColor = [SKColor blackColor];
    subNode.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeCenter;
    [messageNode addChild:subNode];
}
```

Note that since each new line is moved down vertically in relation to the parent node, when you place `messageNode` in the scene, the position will be based on the center point of the first line of text, rather than the center point of the entire block of text. That can be fixed easily by adjusting the center point of messageNode down by totalHeight/2 - lineHeight/2. See the `backgroundNode.position` line in the background code below.

**I wrote some code to create a background for the block of text as well:**

```
    //Get widest child frame
    NSInteger frameWidth = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < [messageNode.children count]; i++){
        if([messageNode.children objectAtIndex:i].frame.size.width > frameWidth){
            frameWidth = [messageNode.children objectAtIndex:i].frame.size.width;
        }
    }

    NSInteger singleLineHeight = [messageNode.children objectAtIndex:0].frame.size.height;
    NSInteger lineCount = [messageNode.children count];
    NSInteger totalFrameHeight = singleLineHeight * lineCount;

    CGSize backgroundFrameSize = CGSizeMake(frameWidth * 1.1, totalFrameHeight * 1.5);
    CGFloat cornerRadius = 10;
    SKShapeNode *backgroundNode = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithRectOfSize:backgroundFrameSize cornerRadius:cornerRadius];

    //Bump the frame down so it is vertically centered around all lines of text, rather than vertically centered on the first line.
    backgroundNode.position = CGPointMake(0, -(totalFrameHeight/2 - singleLineHeight/2) );
    backgroundNode.zPosition = -1;
    [messageNode addChild:backgroundNode];
```